# How to pull specific values from a nested JSON array in Postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to pull a specific set of values to insert them into a table in Postgres. I tried using json_populate_recordset, but got nothing.

The basic structure is this:

```
{
    "array_group": [
        {"field1" : "value1", "field2" : "value2"},
        {"field1" : "value3", "field2" : "value4"}
    ]
}
```

Is there another function I should be using or should I try reformatting my JSON structure instead?

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, what I'm trying to do is pull the values from the fields separately so I can insert them into reference tables in the database.

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (row1)
SELECT field1 FROM array_group

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (row2)
SELECT field2 FROM array_group
```